# Plotting timeseries with uneven period in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I would like to plot a timeseries of the cumsum of edit of that occurred in on a Wikipedia Category.

The timeseries is created.

```
In [157]:

type(edits)

Out[157]:

pandas.core.series.TimeSeries

In [158]:

edits.tail()

Out[158]:

2013-03-31 14:37:38    53254
2013-06-12 20:56:40    53255
2013-12-22 12:14:43    53256
2013-12-22 19:16:07    53257
2013-12-26 14:19:59    53258
Name: edits, dtype: int64
```

However when. I go run `edit.plot()` I get the error `AssertionError: Index length did not match values`. I am able to run the example from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot perfectly. The one difference I can see is that the example timeseries, the times are evenly spaced - I.e. every one day, or 5 hours. But in my data, the difference between times is not even. Is it still possible to get pandas to plot this timeseries?

Comment: Normally a non evenly spaced timeseries is not a problem. Can you provide a reproducable example that fails?

Comment: Ahh, in trying to reproduce the data, I came across my solution. The problem was that the TimeSeries was not sorted! Once I called `.sort()` on my TimeSeries the plot was perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add that as self-answer?